# Django Rest Framework Choices Field Serializer

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Using Django Rest Framework 3.6.3, I have a choices CharField in my model:

```
# models.py
class User(AbstractUser):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

# viewsets.py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

I'm posting to the endpoint:

```
 { 'gender': 'M' }
```

When I GET the endpoint, I want it to show:

```
{ 'gender': 'Male' }
```

With the following serializer, it displays the display value of the choice (Male) instead of the value (M), but it doesn't save:

```
# serializers.py 
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # for some reason on save, gender is None??
    gender = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def get_gender(self, obj):
        return obj.get_gender_display()
```

If I add a `to_internal_value` method then it works fine (displays the gender choice display value, but also saves:

```
# serializers.py 
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    gender = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def get_gender(self, obj):
        return obj.get_gender_display()

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # if I add a to_internal_value that does nothing, it saves??
        return data
```

Why does this work?  Is there a more obvious way I should write this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overriding `to_internal_value` works because you bypass the per field `to_internal_value` call.

An alternative solution would be:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    gender = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=User.GENDER_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

Answer (score 2):

why don't you place `get_gender_display` inside `fields`? like this:

```
# serializers.py 
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = 'foo...', 'get_gender_display'
```